# Multiple WillPopScope?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

this is the scenario of my app:
***Splash Screen*** -> ***Login Screen*** -> ***Home Screen***

I have `WillPopScope` in my **Login Screen** and also in my **Home Screen**.

If the user has successfully logged in, I use:

```
Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
```

The problem I have is that, I am now in my **Home Screen** but when I try to press the back button of my phone, the `WillPopScope` of my **Login Screen** is being triggered instead of the **Home Screen** ?

I'm new to flutter and I'm having trouble with this simple logic. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in **Login Screen** you need pop Login Screen from stack and push Home screen into it. You can do that with:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working =(. I've also tried `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
          ),
          (_) => false);` also not working.

Comment: It wasn't able to use the WillPopScope properly. I should return false to override the default function of the back button. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Login Screen add `Navigator.pop(context)` before call Home Screen.

```
Navigator.pop(context);
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
```